# How to work with large data on a computing cluster

Tags: python, bigdata, bioinformatics, hpc

I have a 150GB CSV file (single-cell RNA-seq, 1.1 million rows, 31,000 columns, all but one column are 16-bit floats) that I need to work with, so I have to load it all into RAM. I have access to a computing cluster. Should I be focusing on increasing the number of cores, the amount of memory allocated per core, or some other parameter to make this work?

I'm looking to subset the data into separate files and process them separately using gene co-expression analysis packages, and marker gene analyses using Seurat.

I have access to nodes with 192GB RAM, with 48 cores per node

Comment: The question is very vague to be able provide a useful answer. How much RAM do you have? What is the computing cluster hardware used (number of core, amount of memory and bandwidth, number of nodes, network, accelerators, etc.)? What kind of computation do you want to do? Please complete the question with much more precisions/informations.

Comment: 1.1E6*31E3*16 is approx 272 GB. So it wouldn't fit in RAM. Also, would RNA just be a very long string of G,U,A,C? CSV stands for "comma separated values" and I would think your file does not have commas. I would think that whatever you choose for gene coexpression analysis and marker gene analysis would have a strong influence on your solution, too. But if you can split up your very large file into smaller files, that could probably be accomplished by either reading line by line or by reading in chunks and suggested by @tHeReaver

Answer (score 0):

Pandas already comes prepared to solve this problem with the `read_csv()` method.
You have the chunksize argument that specifies the chunk you want to process each time and returns you TextFileReader object for iteration.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

path = "foo.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path, chunksize = 10**6)
```

More read about [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Being that you are using HPC you can give a larger chunksize, however this is still better to work with this and a context manager than to just brute force load the entire file to memory at once.

Comment: After doing the above, consider converting it to the loom format for large multidimensional data. I've had very pleasant experiences manipulating scRNA data in loom format https://linnarssonlab.org/loompy/